# Might be a runaway multi-line "" string starting

Tags: perl

syntax error at HTMLmaker.pl line 54, near ". if"
  (Might be a runaway multi-line "" string starting on line 47)
Execution of HTMLmaker.pl aborted due to compilation errors.

```
 use strict;
use warnings;
use vars qw( $fc $sc $fontsize );

print "What would you like the title of the website to be? ";
chomp (my $TWT = <STDIN>);
print "What would you like as the background colour?
It will be a gradient, enter your top colour ";
chomp (my $firstecolour = <STDIN>);
print "Choose your second colour ";
chomp (my $secondcolour = <STDIN>);
print "How large would you like the text to be, 6 = smallest, 1 = largest ";
chomp (my $size = <STDIN>);
print "What text would you your heading to be? ";
chomp (my $text = <STDIN>);
print "What size would you like your font?";
chomp (my $fontsize = <STDIN>);
print "What font would you like?";
chomp (my $category = <STDIN>);
print "What colour would like your text to be?";
chomp (my $col = <STDIN>);
print "What would you like to put as tour first paragraph?";
chomp (my $txt = <STDIN>);
print "Would you like your text aligned in the center?";
chomp (my $ali = <STDIN>);
if ($firstecolour eq "black") { $fc = "#000000" };
if ($firstecolour eq "red") { $fc = "#FF0000" };
if ($firstecolour eq "green") { $fc = "#00FF00" };
if ($firstecolour eq "blue") { $fc = "#0000FF" };
if ($firstecolour eq "yellow") { $fc = "#FFFF00" };
if ($firstecolour eq "cyan") { $fc = "#00FFFF" };
if ($firstecolour eq "pink") { $fc = "#FF00FF" };
if ($firstecolour eq "grey") { $fc = "#C0C0C0" };
if ($firstecolour eq "white") { $fc = "#FFFFFF" };
if ($secondcolour eq "black") { $sc = "#000000" };
if ($secondcolour eq "red") { $sc = "#FF0000" };
if ($secondcolour eq "green") { $sc = "#00FF00" };
if ($secondcolour eq "blue") { $sc = "#0000FF" };
if ($secondcolour eq "yellow") { $sc = "#FFFF00" };
if ($secondcolour eq "cyan") { $sc = "#00FFFF" };
if ($secondcolour eq "pink") { $sc = "#FF00FF" };
if ($secondcolour eq "grey") { $sc = "#C0C0C0" };
if ($secondcolour eq "white") { $sc = "#FFFFFF" };

my $filename = "./index.htm";
open (LOG, ">>$filename") or die $!;
print LOG "<html>
<title>$TWT</title>
<body style=\"height: 800px; width: 1247px; filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Gradient(endColorstr=\'$sc\', startColorstr=\'$fc\', gradientType=\'0\');\">
<DIV ALIGN=CENTER>
<h$size>$text</h>
</DIV>
<font size=\"$fontsize\" face=\"$category\" color=\"$col\">
". if ($ali eq "yes") { print "<DIV ALIGN=CENTER>"}; ."
<p>$txt</p></font>
". if ($ali eq "yes") { print "</DIV>"}; ."
</body>
</html>";
close (LOG);
<STDIN>;
```

Whats wrong with this please?

Comment: You mean besides the fact that you're not using hashes for the colour name to hex code mapping, you're using the two-argument version of `open()`, you don't `uc()` the input (what if someone enters `Black` for a colour?), you are using a typeglob for a filehandle, and you're not consistently printing to the filehandle? :-)

Answer (score 7):

The `if` statement in Perl can not be part of an expression, it is a stand alone construct.  If you want to place it inside of an expression, it must be wrapped in a `do {...}` block.

The inline equivalent is the `COND ? EXPR1 : EXPR2` construct which is the same as `do {if (COND) {EXPR1} else {EXPR2}}`.

You should use lexical variables declared with `my` rather than the `use vars` pragma.

Your code also contains a good deal of repetition.  Perl is very good at letting you eliminate this, which saves time, eases refactoring, and cuts down on errors.

For example, mapping color names to hex codes should be done with a hash table.  Similarly, setting many variables after prompting the user could be written as a loop.

Here is a short example of what I mean:

```
my @questions = (
    [\my $TWT           => "What would you like the title of the website to be? "],
    [\my $firstecolour  => "What would you like as the background colour?\nIt will be a gradient, enter your top colour: "],
    [\my $secondcolour  => "Choose your second colour: "],
);

for (@questions) {
    print $$_[1];
    chomp (${$$_[0]} = <STDIN>)
}

my %colors = do {
    no warnings 'qw';
    qw(
        black   #000000
        red     #FF0000
        green   #00FF00
        blue    #0000FF
        yellow  #FFFF00
        cyan    #00FFFF
        pink    #FF00FF
        grey    #C0C0C0
        white   #FFFFFF
    )
};

for ($firstecolour, $secondcolour) {
    if ($colors{lc $_}) {
        $_ = $colors{lc $_}
    }
}

say for $firstecolour, $secondcolour;
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot inline your `if` statement as you did.
`". if ($ali eq "yes") { print "…"}; ."…"; close (LOG); ;`
==>

```
";
if ($ali eq "yes") { print LOG "…"};
print LOG "…";
close (LOG);
```

Comment: Though you can use a conditional operator instead of the if.  print "foo".($ali eq "yes"?"<DIV>…":"")."<p>…";

Answer (score 2):

You have a printing instruction in the middle of a string expression. This is wrong on two counts:

- In Perl, you can't directly embed an instruction (an order to do something) inside an expression (a description of how to build up a value).
- The printing instruction `print "<DIV ALIGN=CENTER>"` would print that text to standard output, not include it in what you're printing to `LOG`.

The problematic part of your code is this:

```
print LOG "<html> …
". if ($ali eq "yes") { print "<DIV ALIGN=CENTER>"}; ."
… </html>";
```

`if` can't be used in an expression, but you can use the [conditional operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Conditional-Operator) `condition ? if_true : if_false` instead.

```
print LOG "<html> …
" . ($ali eq "yes" ? "<DIV ALIGN=CENTER>" : "") . "
… </html>";
```

Another Perl feature that would be useful in this part of the code is the [“here-document” syntax](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#%3c%3cEOF). It's a simpler way of writing multiline strings. You put a `<<EOF` placeholder as the argument to `print`, and all the lines until one that contains just `EOF` become one long string. The [`@{[…]}` idiom](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html#Using-References) to put a variable expression is a little trickier to explain; if this worries you, put the variable parts in variables beforehand and just use those variables.

```
print LOG <<EOF;
<html> …
@{[$ali eq "yes" ? "<DIV ALIGN=CENTER>" : ""]}
<p>$txt</p></font>
@{[$ali eq "yes" ? "</DIV>" : ""]}
… </html>
EOF
```

or

```
my $ali_start = ($ali eq "yes" ? "<DIV ALIGN=CENTER>\n" : "");
my $ali_end = ($ali eq "yes" ? "</DIV>\n" : "");
print LOG <<EOF;
<html> …
$ali_start<p>$txt</p></font>$ali_end
… </html>
EOF
```

Follow [Eric Strom's advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6063473/might-be-a-runaway-multi-line-string-starting/6063878#6063878) on general Perl style, as well.